# Dual state machine in a List Comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Consider the following function:

```
def search( seq, start, end ):
    state = 0
    ret = []
    aux = []
    for i in seq:
        if state == 0:
            if i == start:
                aux = [i]
                state = 1
        elif state == 1:
            aux.append(i);
            if i == end:
                ret.append(aux)
                state = 0
    return ret
```

The `search()` function is a very basic dual state machine, which returns a list of sublists using the `start` and `end` as delimiters. For example:

```
DNA = ['CGC','UUC','GCU','UUG','GAA','AAU','UUG','UGU','GUU','UUU','UGU',
       'GGC','UGC','UCG','CUG','CUC','AAA','UUG','UUC','GCU','GCU','UUU',
       'UGU','GUC','CUG','GCU','GCU','UUU','AUU','AUU','AAU','CGC','UGC',
       'UUG','GCG','GUU','CUG','UUA','CGC','UGC','UUG','GGC','UUG','UUG',
       'UGG','CUU','UGG','UUG','UUU','GUA','UAU','UGA','GCU','GUU','CUU',
       'UGG','CUU','UGG','AAU','UUU','GUU','UAU','UAG','GCU','GCU','CUU',
       'GUU','GUU','GUU','GCU','UGU','UGU','AAU','GUU','GGC']


print( search( DNA, start='AAU', end='GUU') )
```

Output:

```
[['AAU', 'UUG', 'UGU', 'GUU'], ['AAU', 'CGC', 'UGC', 'UUG', 'GCG', 'GUU'], ['AAU', 'UUU', 'GUU'], ['AAU', 'GUU']]
```

Is it possible to write an equivalent function using `list comprehension` ?

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: Some pythonic feeling nudged me with this possibility.

Comment: Is a for loop UN-Pythonic?

Comment: is it ?! the challenge is cast.

Comment: It may be possible but I'm sure it wouldn't be very comprehensible but just ugly.

Comment: Do you need to handle overlapping sequence? Seems like something for numpy.

Comment: @alvas non-overlapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure a comprehension is the right tool for this task. You could, however, write a very pythonic [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators):

```
def search(seq, start, end):
    ret = []
    for i in seq:
        if i == start or ret:
            ret.append(i)
        if i == end and ret:
            yield ret
            ret = []

>>> list(search(DNA, start='AAU', end='GUU'))
[['AAU', 'UUG', 'UGU', 'GUU'],
 ['AAU', 'CGC', 'UGC', 'UUG', 'GCG', 'GUU'],
 ['AAU', 'UUU', 'GUU'],
 ['AAU', 'GUU']]
```

If you really desire a comprehension, you could use some molestation of `takewhile` and `dropwhile`:

```
 from itertools import takewhile as t, dropwhile as d
 it = iter(DNA)
 [x+[end] for x in (list(t(lambda i: i!=end, d(lambda i: i!=start, it))) for x in range(DNA.count(end))) if x]
```

This is ugly though and I am sure it has some issues :) an occurrence of `start` after the last `end` for example...

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is the subset of the list given the start and end value of that's found within the list.
First, you could have reduced your search space with this:

```
start_index = seq.index(start)
end_index = seq.index(end)
seq[start_index:end_index+1]
```

Then, you can iteratively search within the space for more starts and ends. Since there is no overlap sequence, you could try:

```
def search(seq, start, end):
    while start in seq:
        start_index = seq.index(start)
        end_index = seq.index(end) 
        if end_index > start_index:
            yield seq[start_index:end_index+1]
        seq = seq[end_index+1:]



DNA = ['CGC','UUC','GCU','UUG','GAA','AAU','UUG','UGU','GUU','UUU','UGU',    
       'GGC','UGC','UCG','CUG','CUC','AAA','UUG','UUC','GCU','GCU','UUU',    
       'UGU','GUC','CUG','GCU','GCU','UUU','AUU','AUU','AAU','CGC','UGC',    
       'UUG','GCG','GUU','CUG','UUA','CGC','UGC','UUG','GGC','UUG','UUG',    
       'UGG','CUU','UGG','UUG','UUU','GUA','UAU','UGA','GCU','GUU','CUU',    
       'UGG','CUU','UGG','AAU','UUU','GUU','UAU','UAG','GCU','GCU','CUU',    
       'GUU','GUU','GUU','GCU','UGU','UGU','AAU','GUU','GGC']

start='AAU'
end='GUU'

list(search(DNA, start='AAU', end='GUU'))
```

---

Alternatively (though totally "unpythonic" in any zense), you can use `numpy.searchsorted` given the indices of the start and end:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

DNA = ['CGC','UUC','GCU','UUG','GAA','AAU','UUG','UGU','GUU','UUU','UGU',    
       'GGC','UGC','UCG','CUG','CUC','AAA','UUG','UUC','GCU','GCU','UUU',    
       'UGU','GUC','CUG','GCU','GCU','UUU','AUU','AUU','AAU','CGC','UGC',    
       'UUG','GCG','GUU','CUG','UUA','CGC','UGC','UUG','GGC','UUG','UUG',    
       'UGG','CUU','UGG','UUG','UUU','GUA','UAU','UGA','GCU','GUU','CUU',    
       'UGG','CUU','UGG','AAU','UUU','GUU','UAU','UAG','GCU','GCU','CUU',    
       'GUU','GUU','GUU','GCU','UGU','UGU','AAU','GUU','GGC']

start='AAU'
end='GUU'

arr = pd.Series(DNA)
start_indices = arr[arr == start].index
end_indices = arr[arr == end].index
for start_idx, end_idx in np.column_stack((start_indices, end_indices[np.searchsorted(end_indices, start_indices, side='right')])):
    print(DNA[start_idx:end_idx+1])
```

`numpy` answer from [Given 2 list of integers how to find the non-overlapping ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47047588/given-2-list-of-integers-how-to-find-the-non-overlapping-ranges)

Comment: There are duplicates in the sample data and you'd have to use `end_index + 1`,  I guess